# Error while using for_each

Tags: c++, graph, foreach

I have the following 2 functions in my code:

```
bool num()
{
    return 0;
}

void setDFS()
{
    int i = 0;
    project3::Graph<string, string> g1;

    std::for_each(g1.Vertice1.begin(), g1.Vertice1.end(),num);

}
```

What the function does is for each Vertice in vector Vertice1, it has to set its number to 0 for now. Once I start graph traversing, later on I would be incrementing the num to the traversed count.

While compiling, I am getting "
error C2197: 'bool (__cdecl *)(void)' : too many arguments for call" error.

```
template <class VertexType, class EdgeType> class Vertex{
protected:
    VertexType vertice;
    EdgeType edge;

public:

};

std::vector<project3::Vertex<VertexType, EdgeType>*> Vertice1;
```

Comment: What is type of `Vertice1`? Post more code..

Comment: It is of type name class Vertex: std::vector<project3::Vertex<VertexType, EdgeType>*> Vertice1;

Comment: I know its not readable... Hence I removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) algorithm receives a [unary function](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/UnaryFunction.html) which should have the following signature:

```
void function(T&);
```

where T is the type of element of g1.Vertice1 vector:

```
template <class VertexType, class EdgeType>
void num(project3::Vertex<VertexType, EdgeType>* v) {
  *v = 0; // <- Maybe v->set(0,0,0)
}
```

Comment: FYI, `typename` is unnecessary here, `void num(project3::Vertex<VertexType, EdgeType>* v)` is standard conformant.

Comment: OK, I'll remove "typename" from num() argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [SGI site](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/for_each.html):

> For_each applies the function object f to each element in the range [first, last); f's return value, if any, is ignored.

And

> A Unary Function is a kind of function object: an object that is called as if it were an ordinary C++ function. A Unary Function is called with a single argument.

As far as I understood from the documentation, the `for_each` construct will iterate over the passed collection and pass the current element to your function, in which you then need to update the passed item accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

From a previous experience with what I think is the same program/same user, I would say that num needs to take a string argument, as it needs something to operate on (look at the declaration of the third argument to the std::for_each() method in your headers).

Also, if the num() method is part of an object, I don't think it will work directly (because of C++'s implicit "this" argument to member functions.)

A possible soloution is a non-member wrapper around this function, like so:

```
void my_non_member(string str)
{
    myobj.my_member(str); // myobj is a reference to a Vertice object that must be  
    // initialised elsewhere.
}
```